# Change img src on click jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a gallery of images, when I click one of the gallery items a popup window shows up, each item has a different image src. I'd like to make this gallery dynamic so when the user click on an item, the image of the corresponding item should show in the popup window. I hope this doesn't sound confusing, here's an image to illustrate what I'm trying to say:

[image: Gallery]

[image: Popup Window]

And the HTML:

```
<div class="gallery__flex">
        <div class="gallery__item">
          <img src="img/gallery-1.jpeg" alt="" class="gallery__img">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery__item">
          <img src="img/gallery-2.jpeg" alt="" class="gallery__img">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery__item">
          <img src="img/gallery-3.jpeg" alt="" class="gallery__img">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery__item">
          <img src="img/gallery-4.jpeg" alt="" class="gallery__img">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="gallery__flex">
        <div class="gallery__item">
          <img src="img/gallery-5.jpeg" alt="" class="gallery__img">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery__item">
          <img src="img/gallery-6.jpeg" alt="" class="gallery__img">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery__item">
          <img src="img/gallery-7.jpeg" alt="" class="gallery__img">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery__item">
          <img src="img/gallery-8.jpeg" alt="" class="gallery__img">
        </div>

  <!-- popup window -->

    <div class="popup">
      <img src="img/gallery-1.jpeg" alt="" class="popup__img">
      <span class="popup__close-icon" id="closeIcon">&times;</span>
    </div>
```

How can I do this using Jquery?

Answer (score 0):

I made an example:
https://codepen.io/dknacht/pen/dKaONp

Use the $.prop function to access the source attribute and change it.
If you bind the image with a click event, then `src = $(this).prop("src")` will return the source.
You will have to set the source, to the image, in the popup as `$("idToImageInPopup").prop("src", src)`.

```
$("img").click(function (){
  $("#imageDialog").prop("src", $(this).prop("src"))
  $("#dialog").dialog("open")
});
```

Comment: Thank you for replying @Dknacht, this is the code that I'm using and it's not working:    `// Popup open
  $('.gallery__item').click(function() {
    $('.popup').css({
      'opacity': '1',
      'visibility': 'visible'});
    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
    $(".popup").prop("src", $(this).prop("src"))
  })`

Comment: Replace `$('.gallery__item').click(` with `$('.gallery__item>img').click(` to attach the click event to the image, not the div containing the image. What happens is that you (in your code) are attaching the click event to the `<div>` element. The div has no "src" property, so you code does not work. by `$(".gallery__item>img")` you attach the click event to the image inside the div, not the div itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code, when you click img it show popup of img

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  
  $(".gallery__item>img").click(function(){
    var img = $(this).attr('src');
    $(".popup>img.popup__img").attr('src',img);
    $(".popup").show();
  });
  $("#closeIcon").click(function(){
    $(".popup").hide();
  });
  

});
```

```css
.gallery__img{
  width:80px;
  height:80px;
  float:left;
}

.popup{
margin-top:10px;
width:100%;
float:left;
border:1px solid #ccc;
padding:10px;
box-sizing:border-box;
position:relative;
display:none;
}
.popup__img{
  width:80px;
  height:80px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  display:block;
  margin:auto;
}
#closeIcon{
position:absolute;
right:0;
top:0;
z-index:1;
font-size:18px;
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
color:#fff;
padding:2px;
box-sizing:border-box;
o
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery__flex">
        <div class="gallery__item">
          <img src="https://cdn2.tgdd.vn/Products/Images/42/166247/samsung-galaxy-a8-star-2018-600x600.jpg" alt="" class="gallery__img">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery__item">
          <img src="https://cdn1.tgdd.vn/Products/Images/42/155261/oppo-f7-bac-600x600.jpg" alt="" class="gallery__img">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery__item">
          <img src="https://cdn3.tgdd.vn/Products/Images/42/84798/samsung-galaxy-j7-prime-hh-600x600.jpg" alt="" class="gallery__img">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery__item">
          <img src="https://cdn.tgdd.vn/Products/Images/42/154260/huawei-nova-3e-2-600x600.jpg" alt="" class="gallery__img">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="gallery__flex">
        <div class="gallery__item">
          <img src="https://cdn2.tgdd.vn/Products/Images/42/177047/samsung-galaxy-s9-tim-1-600x600.jpg" alt="" class="gallery__img">
        </div>
       </div>

  <!-- popup window -->

    <div class="popup">
      <img src="img/gallery-1.jpeg" alt="" class="popup__img">
      <span class="popup__close-icon" id="closeIcon">&times;  </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works perfectly. Now do you mind explaining what this piece of code actually does `$(".gallery__item>img")`

Comment: What happens is that you (in your code) are attaching the click event to the `<div>` element. The div has no "src" property, so you code does not work. by `$(".gallery__item>img")` you attach the click event to the image inside the div, not the div itself.

Comment: Ohh I see, that makes sense. Thank you very much for the explaining that to me.